# Get the exception object thrown from celery group tasks

Tags: exception, celery, celery-task

I have a group object. I wan't to wait until all of the tasks finish and print their results. This is my code:

```
tasks = [my_task.s(some_val=val).set(queue='different_q') for val in val_list]
job = group(tasks)
job_result = job.apply_async()
results = job_result.get()
```

If everything goes as expected then in results i get

```
[val1, val2, val3]
```

But if one of the tasks throws an exception, the `job_result.get()` throws an exception.
I know in `chord` i can propagate the exception but i can't find the proper way to do so in `group`. 
This is the wanted result:

```
[val1, Exception('some exception'), val3]
```

and that the `job_result.get()` won't throw an exception.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding the solution to this?